# Check if input is any of the values in an array

Tags: java

I want to be able to check if the string input matches any of the strings in array, and then run only if it matches any of the strings.

```
String[] list = {"hey","hello"};

if (input == anyofthestringsinarray) {

}
```

Thought something like `if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(list)) {}` could work, but dont. Any tips?

Comment: Iterate through the array and compare.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static void stringContainsItemFromList(String inputStr, String[] items)
{
    for(int i =0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        if(inputStr.contains(items[i]))
        {
           // if present do something
        }
    }
}
```